# Why am I counting 0 words?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I am using C. The goal is to take input, and count the characters, words, and lines...using switch statement instead of if statements. I count characters and lines fine, but I keep getting 0 words. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */

int main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    printf("Please input some text!\n");

    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;

        switch(c)
        {
            case '\n':
                c = '\n'; 
                ++nl; break;
            case IN:
                c = IN;
                ++nw; break;
        }
    }
    printf("Characters %d\nWords %d\nLines %d\n", nc, nw, nl);
    return 0;
}
```

The goal is to do this below using switch statement.

```
if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
```

Comment: `case IN:` means "when the read character is equal to `'\1'`," which is presumably never happening. You seem to get your `c` and `state` variables confused in multiple places.

Comment: C != C++. You should generally not cross-tag, especially when learning one (and not knowing the other).

Answer (score 2):

To translate the code in your updated code to use a switch, this is what you need to do

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */

int main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;

    printf("Please input some text!\n");

    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;

        switch(c)
        {
            case '\n':
                ++nl;
            case ' ':
            case '\t':
                state = OUT;
                break;
            default:
                if (state == OUT)
                    ++nw;
                state = IN;
                break;
        }

    }
    printf("Characters %d\nWords %d\nLines %d\n", nc, nw, nl);
    return 0;
}
```

in your original code, you are never changing the value of `state`, and the `case IN` will never occur since you are checking that the value returned from `getchar()` is `'\1'` which it will never be, so `nw` is not being incremented.

Comment: Your code will not treat consecutive `' '` characters cleanly and will end up counting more words than there are. Try your program with `abcd`, three spaces, and `xyz` as input and see what output you get.

Comment: Thanks iharob, RSahu. In the default block, why the ++nw before state = IN?

Comment: The number of lines is the number of `'\n'` if the last `char` is an `'\n`.  Else the number of lines needs a +1.  The easiest way to do that is to count the number of times the _previous_ `char` is `\n` and initialize `int previous  = '\n'`.

Comment: @kits, because if you set `state = IN` then `state != OUT` and you wont count any lines, do you know [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?